# Access an app's subfolder while the app is itself in a subfolder

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have an app (Symfony) in a folder `rapp` and I'd like to access via `example.com/rapp/`.

The `index.php` file is in a `rapp/public/` folder.

So I'd like to have all my requests to `/rapp/` to rewrite to `/rapp/public/index.php`.

After many times reading the docs I have this following config:

```
Alias /rapp/ "/var/www/html/rapp/"

<Directory /var/www/html/rapp/>

    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny

   Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /rapp

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php/$1 [QSA,L,NC]

    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I tested this config at [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it seems to be rewriting as I'd like

- [Here is my test](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=c6e754dd-b143-5065-b80a-26de22d05192)

When I copy/paste the results URL (changing the `example.com` ofc) it works, I can access my app, but It still doesn't work with the "input" URL `http://example.com/rapp/admin/***`.

Am I missing something in my config ?

Comment: What's the `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: I tried to add a `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rapp/`but didn't make it work so I removed it. What `DocumentRoot` should I add ? to my rapp folder or public folder ?

Comment: The `DocumentRoot` is really an essential part of your server config - it should be defined _somewhere_? I'm querying this because your `Alias` directive looks out of place / superfluous? Maybe you are using an `Alias` instead??? The `DocumentRoot` should not have a trailing slash.

Comment: The DocumentRoot is /var/www/html. I thjought I edited my comments but seems it didn't worked. although I have anotther inside `/var/www/html` folder so I have to keep the Document Root as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /rapp
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
> ```

This rewrites all requests to `/public/index.php` (in the document root). The `RewriteBase` directive used here is not doing anything.

You should remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely and remove the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

In a *directory* context, the *relative* substitution (no slash prefix) is relative to the directory prefix, ie. `/var/www/html/rapp/`. So, the `RewriteBase` directive is not required.

The `QSA` and `NC` flags are superfluous here. As are the anchors on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* - regex is greedy by default.

The output you are seeing with the `.htaccess` tester tool you linked to is incorrect. (It would seem to be applying the `RewriteBase` directive incorrectly.)

Comment: So the tester is invalid (for that at least) ?
I tried commenting the `RewriteBase` and change the `RewriteRule` as you said (removed the `^` and `$` in the regex and the leading `/` for the path) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I managed to do it by re-enabling .htaccess overwrite and doing that `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]` in my `/var/www/html/rapp/.htaccess`. The thing is the Symfony Framework doens't find the `/rapp/` route, it doesn't seem to be accessible inside a folder... I'll see about the framework routing now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, the tester is invalid in this case. I've encountered a number of bugs/shortcomings with the madewithlove `.htaccess` tester tool you've linked to. (I've submitted a couple of bug reports myself in the past.) In the code you posted the `RewriteBase` directive should not do anything (it only applies to _relative_ path substitutions), yet in the tester tool it is being applied to the root-relative substitution, which is incorrect. It is also affecting how the URL is matched/captured by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ - which is also incorrect.

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether these directives are in a `<Directory>` container in your server config or in `.htaccess`. (Assuming you have restarted Apache after making changes to your server config.) Note, however, that if you have mod_rewrite directives in `.htaccess` then these will completely override (by default) any mod_rewrite directives in a parent `<Directory>` container.

Comment: Note also that `/public/$1` routes the URL differently than `/public/index.php/$1` in your question - the later uses PATH_INFO to route the URL, whereas `/public/$1` does not (probably using `REQUEST_URI`) and requires mod_dir to make an internal subrequest to `index.php` (an unnecessary extra step).

Comment: So I have to redirect to `/public/index.php/$1`. I, more or less, guessed that after few tries. But I don't understand why my RewriteRule in .conf file and `Directory` Directives is not working while the exact same `Rewrite` in `.htaccess` is working.
Like I said, with `.htaccess` it works, but it seems there is problem with the php framework I'm using to match the Routes.